# java.lang.VerifyError with Mockito 1.10.17

Tags: java, testng, mockito, jmock

I am trying to replace JMock with Mockito (1.10.17). I have already done some unit tests successfully, but now I want to use the timeout feature

```
verify(publisher, timeout(5000)).notifySubscribers(any(BecameMasterMessage.class));
```

and I get this exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/mockito/internal/verification/VerificationOverTimeImpl, method: verify signature: (Lorg/mockito/internal/verification/api/VerificationData;)V) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.mockito.verification.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.java:32)
    at org.mockito.verification.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.java:25)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.timeout(Mockito.java:2164)
```

The issue happens in IntelliJ and with Maven. There is only 1 version of Mockito on the classpath. There is also JMock 2.5.1 on the classpath which I cannot remove since 99% of my unit tests still use JMock at this moment. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

UPDATE: I tried with JMock 2.6.0 and Hamcrest 1.3 but the result is the same.

UPDATE 2:

This works:

```
Thread.sleep( 5000 );
verify( m_publisher ).notifySubscribers( any( BecameMasterMessage.class ) );
```

And this does not:

```
verify(publisher, timeout(5000)).notifySubscribers(any(BecameMasterMessage.class));
```

UPDATE 3:
I have made a small test project that has the exact same problem: See https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/mockito-verify-problem and run it from IntelliJ or with Maven.

Comment: This is a silly "turn it off and on again" question, but it bears asking: Have you cleaned out your compilation artifacts? Even if there's only one version of Mockito on the classpath, VerificationOverTimeImpl is newly renamed from 1.9.5's VerificationWithTimeoutImpl and if you've ever used 1.9.5 or earlier some lingering class file may be throwing everything off.

Comment: @JeffBowman I did do a `mvn clean install` to make sure that was not the issue. I have now edited the question with a link to a sample project that shows the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is an unfortunate constellation between TestNG, JUnit and Mockto. To fix your issue, you just need to add a dependency to JUnit 4.0 or greater (the most recent version is currently 4.12):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the details:

TestNG, which is apparently your testing framework, declares a dependency to the quite old JUnit version 3.8.1. Mockito does not declare a dependency to JUnit at all but it uses some JUnit classes that were introduced in JUnit 4.0 (!).

**Edit:**

The method `Mockito#timeout()` in your example creates a `Timeout` instance which in turn creates an instance of `VerificationOverTimeImpl`. The method `VerificationOverTimeImpl#verify()` handles an error of type `ArgumentsAreDifferent` which is a subclass of `org.junit.ComparisonFailure`.

From JUnit version 3.8.1 to 4.x the class hierarchy of `ComparisonFailure` changed to having `AssertionError` instead of `Error` as base class. The `VerifiyError` is caused because `VerificationOverTimeImpl#handleVerifyException()` requires an `AssertionError` but would be invoked with an `Error` when JUnit 3.8.1 is used.

Comment: Thanks, will fix it like that now. Would it not be better than for mockito to declare a dependency on JUnit? Then Maven would have choosen the good JUnit version problem.

Comment: `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit.ArgumentsAreDifferent` extends `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure`, the `VerifyError` is a linkage problem. The JVM thinks `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure` in JUnit 3.x and JUnit 4.x are sufficiently different to fail when linking `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit.ArgumentsAreDifferent`. Anyway on the mockito front the issue is that this part of the API should not rely on JUnit.

Comment: This also reveal that Mockito is not anymore compatible with JUnit 3.x

Comment: @Brice Thanks for pointing that out. The problem lies in the class hierarchy of `ComparisonFailure`. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: It seems stefan answered first. His diagnostic is almost correct, however, `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit.ArgumentsAreDifferent` do extends `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure`, that is present in JUnit 3.x and it is a dependency of TestNG 5.x.
The `VerifyError` itself has probably something to do when the JVM is performing the linking as there is changes in the `ComparisonFailure` type itself between JUnit 3.x and JUnit 4.x.

Anyway the issue in Mockito is that it uses a JUnit class where it shouldn't. And that Mockito don't support anymore JUnit 3.x.

**tl;tr**

We have an issue in the code internally the verification mode you are using use a JUnit class, that is not on the classpath. Adding JUnit in the dependency of your POM will fix things.

Thanks for reporting. I've created an issue on [GitHub (#152)](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/152)

**long story**

For some reason TestNG 5.xxx make the JVM fail with a `VerifyError`, on a method that is not even called at that point.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/mockito/internal/verification/VerificationOverTimeImpl, method: verify signature: 
   (Lorg/mockito/internal/verification/api/VerificationData;)V) Incompatible argument to function
```

But switching to the latest version of TestNG, 6.8.something make the JVM fail with an understandable cause : `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/ComparisonFailure
```

Which points to the real issue here, now there's only to find which class depends on JUnit. This class is `ArgumentsAreDifferent` which extends `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure`, this exception appears in a try/catch block in `VerificationOverTimeImpl` that is needed for the timeout verification.

This issue has been there probably since 1.10.x when fixing some timeout issues.

*Note I copied this answer on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/A6D7myKiD5k) as well.*

Comment: You are right, `ArgumentsAreDifferent` extends from `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure`. So my answer is pretty wrong at that point. After investigating the issue a bit further I think the problem is the class hierarchy of `ComparisonFailure`. It is a subclass of `AssertionFailedError` which is a subclass of `Error` in JUnit 3.8.1 **but** a subclass of `AssertionError` in JUnit 4.x. When modifying the 3.8.1 version of `AssertionFailedError` to be a subclass of `AssertionError` everything works well.

Comment: @StefanFerstl Good catch! It's most probable that JVM sees this hierarchy change as an error when it performs linking.