# Is there any way to do timeout verification in Mockito with TestNG

Tags: java, mockito, timeout, powermockito, verify

I'm new to Mockito and PowerMockito. I have a test case which needs to wait for some time until one mocked method is invoked. So I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944202/mockito-wait-for-an-invocation-that-matches-arguments) and tried to use Mockito time verification to verify the method invocation. 
But I only use TestNG, but not Junit in my project. Therefore this test case fails with the following exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/ComparisonFailure

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.mockito.verification.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.java:32)
    at org.mockito.verification.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.java:25)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.timeout(Mockito.java:2164)
    at org.test.scanners.common.ScannerControllerTest.testCancelScan(ScannerControllerTest.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
```

To resolve this issue, as per the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721621/java-lang-verifyerror-with-mockito-1-10-17),we need to add the JUnit into our project as a dependency.

This is my test case **after adding the JUnit** dependency and it works fine. It takes some time to hit the actual method, *methodToTest()*. That's why I need to wait some time until it's get invoked.

```
@Test
public void testCase() {
     ......
     Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.timeout(50000).times(1)).methodToTest();
}
```

Are there any way to do this method invoke verification withot adding the JUnit into my project?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I edited the question with the full stack trace.

Comment: What is the version number of mockito that you are using?

Comment: powermock 1.7.4